# Code First With Existing Database, Entity Framework: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

First off, please do not mark this as duplicate. I know it has been touched several times, but I believe my situation is different. I'm doing a code first approach where the database essentially already existed in some for or another as well.

When I call DbContext.SaveChanges() I receive the following error: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CustomerShippingConfiguration' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF". As you can see in the generated SQL below, Entity Framework is trying to insert 0 into the Id column for a new record.

```
INSERT [dbo].[CustomerShippingConfiguration]([Id], [CustomerId], [AverageCartonWeight], [AverageCartonsPerPallet], [CreatedBy], [Created], [UpdatedBy], [Updated])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7)

-- @0: '0' (Type = Int32)

-- @1: '119' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: '11' (Type = Decimal, Precision = 18, Scale = 2)

-- @3: '11' (Type = Int32)

-- @4: '616' (Type = Int32)

-- @5: '8/9/2016 10:09:08 AM' (Type = DateTime)

-- @6: '616' (Type = Int32)

-- @7: '8/9/2016 10:09:08 AM' (Type = DateTime)
```

This Id column is of type INT and setup as the identity column, primary key, and auto increments.

[image: Identity Column Configuration]

[image: Identity Column Specification]

[image: Table Schema]

The entity model looks like this:

```
public class ShippingConfigurationEntity : EntityBase<ShippingConfigurationEntity>, IEntity
{
      public int CustomerId { get; set; }

      public virtual CustomerEntity Customer { get; set; }

      public decimal? AverageCartonWeight { get; set; }

      public int? AverageCartonsPerPallet { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<ShippingAddressEntity> Addresses { get; set; }

      public ShippingConfigurationEntity()
      {
          Addresses = new List<ShippingAddressEntity>();
      }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T>
{
      public virtual int Id { get; set; }

      public virtual int CreatedBy { get; set; }

      public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

      public virtual int UpdatedBy { get; set; }

      public virtual DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration for the entity looks like this:

```
public class ShippingConfigurationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ShippingConfigurationEntity>
{
    public ShippingConfigurationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.CustomerId).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.AverageCartonsPerPallet).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.AverageCartonWeight).IsOptional();
        Property(t => t.CreatedBy).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Created).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.UpdatedBy).IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.Updated).IsRequired();

        ToTable("CustomerShippingConfiguration");

        HasMany(x => x.Addresses).WithRequired(x => x.ShippingConfiguration).HasForeignKey(x => x.ShippingConfigurationId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

There is a parent entity called Customer that looks similar to this:

```
public class CustomerEntity : EntityBase<CustomerEntity>, IEntity
{
    public int LocationID { get; set; }        

    public virtual ShippingConfigurationEntity ShippingConfiguration { get; set; }
}
```

Where the configuration looks like this:

```
class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<CustomerEntity>
{
    public CustomerConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(t => t.LocationID).IsRequired();

        Ignore(t => t.Created);
        Ignore(t => t.CreatedBy);
        Ignore(t => t.Updated);
        Ignore(t => t.UpdatedBy);

        ToTable("Customer");

        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
        Property(t => t.LocationID).HasColumnName("LOCATION_ID");

        HasOptional(x => x.ShippingConfiguration).WithRequired(x => x.Customer).WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}
```

If I remove the relationship between CustomerEntity and ShippingConfiguration Entity, everythings if I use the following for the Id property on ShippingConfiguration:

```
Property(t => t.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

I have another entity which is setup in a very similar pattern that works just fine. I'm really at a loss here. Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: Not an answer, but what is the point of `EntityBase` having a generic parameter that isn't used?

Comment: Honestly, it's legacy and needs to be removed. It used to serve a purpose, but no longer does.

Comment: Haha fair enough. In that case, you should be aware that writing an [mcve] will likely get your question answered a lot quicker and with less silly questions like mine :)

Comment: Add `[Key]` or `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]` annotation to `Id` property.

Comment: I added some edits to the original question. The issue seems to lye in the relationship defined between the parent entity, CustomerEntity and ShippingConfigurationEntity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your configuration that the database will handle key generation.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class ShippingConfigurationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ShippingConfigurationEntity>
{
    public ShippingConfigurationConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        Property(a => a.Id)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but maybe not with the IsRequired. I believe it produced another error. Let me try and I'll post back. The strange thing is that I don't have to do this with my other entities. It's as if EF just assumes it is database generated by default.

Comment: This produces "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'Id'." Which is perplexing because I feel rather strongly that the above relationship defined for the addresses. As I have mentioned, this pattern is not one that is new to me.

Comment: This now works if I remove the relationship between this and it's parent entity. See the edits in my original question.